# Is this the right way to assign values to struct array with mapping?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct

```
struct userdata
{
    string task;
    bool isdone;
}

userdata[] public userinfo; 

    address public user;

   // mapping (uint[]=>string) public tasksno;
    mapping (address=>userdata[]) public usertask;

    constructor (address _user)
    {
        user=_user;

    }

    function createtask(address _user1, string memory _task)public
    {
        if(user!=_user1)
        {
            user=_user1;
        }
        userinfo.task.push(_task);
        userinfo.isdone.push(false);

        usertask[user]=userinfo;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, in any case this version at least should compile:

```
    function createtask(address _user1, string memory _task) public {
        if (user != _user1) {
            user=_user1;
        }

        userdata memory _data = userdata({
            task: _task,
            isdone: false
        });
        userinfo.push(_data);

        usertask[user] = _data;
    }
```

You can't do something like `userinfo.task.push(_task)` since `userinfo` is an array, not `userinfo.task`. So first you create an element (`_data`), which is a struct, and you push that.

Some examples to learn: https://solidity-by-example.org/structs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code:

I wasn't properly assigning values to the struct elements.

```
    struct userdata
    {
      string task;
      bool isdone;
    }

    userdata[] userinfo; 

    address user;

    mapping (address=>userdata[]) usertask;

    function createtask(address _user1, string memory _task)public
    {
        if(user!=_user1)
        {
            user=_user1;
        }
        userinfo.push(userdata(_task,false));
        usertask[user]=userinfo;
    }

    function readtask(address _user1, uint index) public view returns (userdata memory)
    {
        userdata storage uses=usertask[_user1][index];
        return uses;
    }

    function updatetask(address _user1, uint index) public
    {
        usertask[_user1][index].isdone=true;
    }

    function deletetask(address _user1, uint index) public 
    {
        delete usertask[_user1][index].isdone;
    }

    function taskcount() public view returns (uint)
    {
       return usertask[msg.sender].length;
    }
```